# If $\sum_{m,n}a_{mn}x^m(1-x)^n\equiv 0$, can we conclude $a_{mn}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Assume $\{a_{mn}\}$ are some real numbers between -1 and 1. If we know $$\sum_{m,n}a_{mn}x^m(1-x)^n\equiv0\quad\forall x\in(0,1),$$ can we conclude that $a_{mn}=0$ for all $m,n\geq 0?$

Thanks.

Comment: A possibly useful thought: Say $V$ is the set of _complex_ $z$ such that $|z|<1$ and $|1-z|<1$. The conditions on $a_{n,m}$ imply that $f(z)=\sum a_{n,m}z^n(1-z)^m$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $V$, to a holomorphic function. Now $f(t)=0$ for $t\in(0,1)$, hence $f=0$. And hence the sum of the $k$-th derivatives of the terms also converges to $0$ on compact subsets of $V$...

Comment: Thank you very much. But unfortunately I know basically nothing about complex analysis. Is this function analytic?

Comment: Oh, I didn't say that. Yes, that's the whole point to my comment; the sum converges to something analytic, so one magic complex thing shows it converges to $0$ in a larger set in the plane, and hence another magic complex thing shows the sum of the derivatives also converges to $0$. Which seems like  it _may_ help showing the coefficients vanish, I dunno...

Comment: Thank you again! Following your suggestion, it seems to me that the corresponding coefficients of the derivatives become infinite sums of $a_{mn}$ and then we again have infinitely many linear equations with infinitely many unknowns:(.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't say it was going to work...

Answer (score 4):

Oops. The answer is trivially no - the functions are not linearly independent! (I've been thinking about why one of them is not in the closed span of the others; in fact one of them is in the *span* of the others.)

If you're allowing $m=0$ and $n=0$ then $(-1) + (x) + (1-x)$ is a counterexample (all but three of the coefficients vanish). If you're assuming that $m$ and $n$ are positive then $[-x^2(1-x)] + [x^3(1-x)] + [x^2(1-x)^2]$ is a counterexample.

We're not the only ones who didn't notice... oh well.

Comment: Oh, thanks! How can I miss this counterexample?

Answer (score 1):

Let me just add one thought: We can view this as looking at the real analytic $f(x,y) = \sum a_{mn}x^my^n$ along the line $(t,1-t), t \in \mathbb R.$ Can such an $f$ vanish on a line without being identically $0,$ i.e., without having all $a_{mn} = 0?$ Sure, happens all the time. For example the function $xy$ vanishes on the axes. It's thus clear that for the line $(t,1-t)$ there have to be loads of examples. Here's one: $(x+(1-x))^2 - 1 = x^2 +2x(1-x) + (1-x)^2 -1\equiv 0.$